# How to shift all workspaces to the next (or previous) output

Tags: i3

Let's say I have 3 monitors, or outputs: LEFT, CENTER, and RIGHT. And I have 6 workspaces. The active workspace is marked with a star:

| LEFT | CENTER | RIGHT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1*** | 2, **3*** | 4, **5***, 6 |

How could I trigger the action of **shifting** all the active workspaces to the left/right output, so I don't get torticollis when working a long time in one of the side outputs? The desired result, after "shifting to the right" would be something like this:

| LEFT | CENTER | RIGHT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **5*** | 2, **1*** | 4, **3***, 6 |

I know about `i3-msg move workspace to output next`, but I would like to, at the same time, do that in all my available monitors.

My guess is that I will have to write a little script to parse the name of the outputs, then for each output, move its active workspace to the left/right. But I need some sort of temporary monitor to put the first one in (otherwise I cannot do the shifting).

Or perhaps identifying each workspace ID in the i3-tree, and moving it (by ID, not by "active" state) to its left/right.

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289936/i3wm-how-to-make-multiple-monitors-switch-workspaces-in-a-single-binding) has something related, but not quite. As I understand, OP wants a "big workspace across outputs". I still want i3 approach of "one output shows one workspace at the time", but I want an easy way to shift all the active ones across outputs.